# Dependent DropDownLists in yii

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

Trying to fill the table. There are two dependent fields (in first table - "Departments", in second table - "Doctor". Data for these fields I also take from two different tables). Actually, when I want to select "Department" in first dropDownList, in second dropDownList I need to take "Doctors" only from this "Department". My code: _form.php

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'deps_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'deps_id', CHtml::listData(Deps::model()->findAll(), 'id','department'),
          array(
          'prompt' => 'Choose department',
          'value' => '0',
          'ajax'  => array(
          'type'  => 'POST',
          'url' => CController::createUrl('/mednotes/selectstaff'),
          'update' => '#Mednotes_selectstaffid',   //selector to update value
          'data' => array('deps_id'=>'js:this.value'),
          )      
          )
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'deps_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'staff_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'staff_id', array('empty'=>'Choose doctor'), CHtml::listData(Staff::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'fullname' )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'staff_id'); ?>
</div>
```

my action below

```
public function actionSelectStaff()
    {
    $giatUnit = (!empty($_POST['deps_id'])) ? $_POST['deps_id']: '0';

            $data=Staff::model()->findAll('deps_id=:deps_id',
                            array(':deps_id'=>$giatUnit));


            $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','department');
            foreach($data as $value=>$department)
            {
            echo CHtml::tag('option',array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($department),true);
            }
    }
```

It doesn't work. And also I have this error in firebug - **500 Internal Server Error**
Really need help. Tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is the server error? Check your server (apache?) logs.

Comment: yes,apache. checked log file, 2 errors, both "failed sql-query" kind.

Answer (score 0):

**At first**: to get POST and GET parameters is better to use `Yii::app()->request`:

```
$giatUnit = Yii::app()->request->getParam('deps_id', '0');
```

**At second**: you need to be sure to always use proper casing if you want your links to work on multiple machines. I suggest you rename action to `actionSelectstaff`. Otherwise check `CUrlManager::caseSensitive` value (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#caseSensitive-detail)

**At third**: In the `actionSelectStaff` action you try to get models using `deps_id` field:

```
$data=Staff::model()->findAll('deps_id=:deps_id', array(':deps_id'=>$giatUnit));
```

And further you getting `listData` using `id` and `department` fields:

```
$data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','department');
```

Does it both fields (`department` and `deps_id`) are represented in the `Staff` model? It quite strange.

Comment: thanks, but problem has solved. It was a mistake with value in my action.